# Wikidata SPARQL query to get all images linked from Russian Wikipedia of each human

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I've got this query to return images for humans (Q5) citizens (P27) of the Soviet Union (Q15180):

```
SELECT ?personLabel ?img WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "ru,[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?person wdt:P27 wd:Q15180.
  ?person wdt:P18 ?img  
}
```

How do I modify it so that instead it returns all images from the Russian Wikipedia for each of these humans?

Comment: First, replace `wd:Q15180` with `wd:Q159`. Is it what you want?

Comment: And then you probably should add something like `OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P569 ?birth } OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P570 ?death } FILTER (?death > "1990-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime || !bound(?death) && ?birth > "1920-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime)` to your query. Almost all these *people* are citizens of the modern Russian Federation.

Comment: As for images... In general, they are not "all images from the Russian Wikipedia for each of these humans" Find a way to extract what you want using Wikipedia API, then try to invoke this API using [MWAPI](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI). Or combine Wikidata SPARQL and Wikipedia API in your own way.